# ISPP macros calling emit and expr

Tags: inno-setup

Can ISPP macros call emit and expr?

I have code as follows:

```
#if oemid == "company1"
  ;Company 1
  #define OEMName "Company 1"
  #define OEMDir "..\Customisation\Company1\"
  #Include "P:\Common\Setups\Japanese.iss"
  #define bannerpath OEMDir+"Setup.bmp"
#elif oemid == "company2"
  ;Company 2
  #define OEMName "Company 2"
  #define OEMDir "..\Customisation\Company2\"
  #define bannerpath OEMDir+"Setup.bmp"
  #define OEMIcon "{app}\OEMIcon.ico"
#elif oemid == "Company 3"
  ;Company 3
  #define OEMDir "..\Customisation\Company3\"
etc...
```

with each custom setup built with a stub ISS script that sets the id and includes the main ISS script.

I'm trying to convert this to a generic call which is implemented in the stub script:

```
#expr OEMInit1()
```

and:

```
#define OEMInit1() \
  emit ";Company 1" \
  define OEMDir "..\Customisation\Company1\" \
  define bannerpath OEMDir+"Setup.bmp"
```

This is failing with:

```
[ISPP] Error at 3:23 in macro OEMInit1:
Undeclared identifier: "emit".
```

How do I convince ISPP that it's another directive instead of an identifier?

If I have completely the wrong end of the stick, fell free to hit me with it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to Gavin on the Inno newsgroup who pointed me to #sub

```
#sub OEMInit1
  ;company 1"
  #define public OEMDir "..\Customisation\Company1\"
  #define public bannerpath OEMDir+"Setup.bmp"
#endsub
```

Note the "public" so it can be access in the calling code.